# Passing Two Dimensional array as argument

Tags: java, arrays

How to pass two dimensional array as an argument in Java. For example, my code for getting matrix as input and displaying  is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class matrix {
    int i,j;
    static int[][] a = new int[3][3]; 
    Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        matrix obj = new matrix();
        System.out.println("Enter the Matrix");
        obj.getdate(a); 
        obj.display(a);
    }

    void getdata(int[][] a) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                a[i][j] = one.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    void display(int[][] a) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println("" + a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way of passing a 2D array is not working. What is the right method of passing 2D array as argument?

Comment: change your signature of display method to  `void display(int[][] a)`;

Comment: `is not working` Is this the error/exception message you're receiving? If not, then describe your problem a little better.

Comment: If you get the error message `Cannot resolve method 'getdate(int[][])'` on this line `obj.getdate(a);`, then what do you think about that? What have you tried to solve that problem? And no, "I'm new to Java" is no excuse to try nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access `a` from outside its scope. For this to work, you will need to change the method signature of `display()` to `display(int[][] a)`. This should fit the call you are making when displaying the array values in `obj.display(a);`.

Answer (score 1):

First you should name classes to start with an uppercase, e.g. `Matrix` instead of `matrix` to follow with the Java conventions.

The error appears when calling the method `display` which is defined without parameters. Since the array `a` is a class member field, then you don't need to pass it to `display` because it is already visible to all the class members. So you can simply call it as follows:

```
obj.display();
```

Similarly for the `getdata` method (for which you have a typo when calling it `getdate` instead of `getdata`), you can define it without any parameters:

```
void getdata() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            a[i][j] = one.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

You also don't need to make the array `a` static.